# has_one association creates multiple records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a User model and Shop model. I want to allow user to create only one shop. So in my User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :terms_and_conditions, :acceptance => true
  has_one :shop
end
```

And my shop model looks like this

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But from console if I try to create a new shop for a user that already has one shop, there is no error and commits successfully.

```
[
  #<Shop id: 1, name: "Rabin & Rose Shop", location: "Banepa Kavre Nepal", description: "oho k vhk kl;o jjio ko;k; jljlkj", rating: nil, delivery_service: true, user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-09-27 15:31:57", updated_at: "2017-09-27 15:31:57", img_url: nil>, 
  #<Shop id: 2, name: "jhoney", location: "sins shop", description: "the entire fuck history here", rating: nil, delivery_service: true, user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-09-28 00:55:44", updated_at: "2017-09-28 00:55:44", img_url: nil>, 
  #<Shop id: 3, name: "Thakur Shop", location: "Pulbazar banepa", description: "Our shop has chicken bedroom. you can met call gir...", rating: nil, delivery_service: true, user_id: 2, created_at: "2017-09-28 01:50:40", updated_at: "2017-09-28 01:50:40", img_url: nil>, 
  #<Shop id: 4, name: nil, location: nil, description: nil, rating: nil, delivery_service: true, user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-09-28 03:49:34", updated_at: "2017-09-28 03:49:34", img_url: nil>
]
```

The `user_id = 1` has multiple records.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails association methods (`has_one`, `has_many`, etc...) don't validate your data. Meaning, the data can still be inserted because you have not placed validations on the incoming data at the application layer or at the data layer.

In order to restrict a user from having multiple shops, you must add a unique index at the data layer and if necessary a uniqueness validation at the application layer. Once that is in place, the database won't allow multiple shops to be created for one specific user.

The unique index on the migration should look something like this

```
add_index :shops, :user_id, unique: true
```

With that index, the database will not allow a shop record to be inserted with duplicate `user_id`.

At the application layer, you could add a uniqueness validation on on the user or the user_id on `Shop` or add a validation on `User` that checks for the existence of a `shop` and have it add an error if the validation fails.

This is an example of that

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  validate :one_shop_per_user

  private

  def one_shop_per_user
     if user.shop && user.shop != self
       errors.add(:user, "already has a shop")
     end
  end
end
```

Note that is only one of many solutions to accomplish what you want to do.